# UINavigationBar buttons fire when touch occurs below the bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

It seems that navigation bar button items accept touches some number of pixels below the actual bar.  This is causing problems for me because I have another UIView that is directly below the navigation bar but it won't receive touch events unless you touch it 16 pixels below its y origin.

I have tested this on several projects besides my own and they all seem to behave this way.  Is this expected behavior?  Is there a way to stop it from occurring?

I am developing using IOS 6.

Comment: Yes, it happens. There's nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  At least I know that it is functioning as designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Navigation bar for that view with a custom button.